# Alternate to non-trivial "> child" sub-selection in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, deprecated

The official [documentation for the child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) ('>') states the following:

> Note: The $("> elem", context) selector will be deprecated in a future release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative selectors.

I currently have a selector of the form `$("> thead th:eq(" + columnIndex + ")", context)`.  What alternative syntax is suggested?

I'm aware of the .children() method, which could select the `thead` element, but would require additional selections afterwards.  Multiple selection steps seem less efficient than a single selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can imagine something along the lines of

`context.children("thead").find("th:eq(" + columnIndex + ")")`

Could this work?  Haven't tested it yet.